# Выравнивание элементов top-right to bottom-left css

Tags: css, веб-программирование, выравнивание

Возник вопрос как можно добиться подобного выравнивания, чтоб заполнение начиналось в правом верхнем углу, уходило вниз и если не хватает места, то сдвигалось влево.

Пробовал играться используя фиксированный родительский контейнер и странсформы типа scale с отрицательными значение как для каждого итема, так и для родительского контейнера, но не достиг желаемого результата

[image: Группировка с верхнего правого угла в левый нижний угол]

Answer (score 0):

поставьте контейнеру стиль:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
flex-direction: column;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OobBBp